# Saving an Audio file to external storage and then sharing that file on whatsapp,email etc

Tags: java, android, audio, android-external-storage

I'm busy creating a soundboard app, and I'm struggling to figure the code so that a sound can be shared on email and whatsapp and other apps. I've done research and I tried to code it but with no luck. The audio file isn't even saving on the external storage so that I can share the sound from there. I have already written the permission uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", and that all works. I think its my code on actually saving the audio to external storage.

```
public String copyFiletoExternalStorage(int resourceId, String resourceName){
        String pathSDCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Soundboard/sounds/" + resourceName;
        try{
            InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);
            FileOutputStream out = null;
            out = new FileOutputStream(pathSDCard);
            byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
            int read = 0;
            try {
                while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buff, 0, read);
                }
            } finally {
                in.close();
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            return pathSDCard;              
    }
```

As you can see from above I parse in R.raw.audio, and "audio.mp3" in the parameters of resourceId and resourceName respectively.

The code below shows how I share the audio once its been saved. But obviously because the audio isn't being saved then I cant share it.

```
share1 = findViewById(R.id.share1);
        share1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String sharePath = copyFiletoExternalStorage(R.raw.audio, "audio.mp3");
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(sharePath);
                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("audio/*");
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound"));

            }
        });
```

If you have any idea why its not working please help me. I have tried so many different ways but nothing seems to work.

Comment: this question has nothing to do with android studio, other than the fact that you're using it to develop your app, right ?

Comment: `Uri uri = Uri.parse(sharePath);` That will not do as you cannot convert a file system path to an uri in this way. You should have used `Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(sharePath));`. But even that would not have sufficed as you have to use a file provider and build your uri with FileProvider.getUroFromFile().

Comment: `The audio file isn't even saving on the external storage` Ok. Indeed then there is nothing to share and it was not needed to post that code.

Comment: `String pathSDCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Soundboard/sounds/"` You should add code to check if that directory exists. And if not create it with mkdirs().

Comment: Put Toast()'s in all catch blocks to inform the user about the exception and e.getMessage();

Comment: `and that all works.` What do you mean with that?

Comment: Add `return null;`  in all catch blocks and let the caller of copyFiletoExternalStorage() check for return value null before launching that intent.

Comment: Your PathToSD declaration is wrong, you should not append text like this "/Soundboard/sounds/" Instead create Directory for Soundboard, sounds Like 
```val rootDir =  Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)```
 ```val soundBoardDir = File(rootDir, "Soundboard")
soundBoardDir.mkdir()``` //repeat the same to create "sounds" directory
//create output file
```val outputFile = File(soundsDir, resourceName)```
//pass outputfile to out stream
```FileOutputStream(outputFile)```